# Get Total Branch wise in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT  b.BranchName ,
        pm.AgreementValue
FROM    dbo.Member AS m
        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm ON ( m.PlanId = pm.PlanId )
        INNER JOIN dbo.Branch AS b ON ( b.BranchId = m.BranchId )
```

this is the result of above query

```
BranchName      AgreementValue
------------------------------
abc             60000.00
abc             36000.00
abc             36000.00
xyz             20000.00
xyz             10000.00
```

now i want to get to total of AgreementValue BranchName wise..thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY b.BranchName` with `SUM` like so:

```
SELECT   b.BranchName ,
         SUM(pm.AgreementValue) TotalValue
FROM     dbo.Member AS m
         INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm ON ( m.PlanId = pm.PlanId )
         INNER JOIN dbo.Branch AS b ON ( b.BranchId = m.BranchId )
GROUP BY b.BranchName;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the total on each row, then use the window function for `sum()`:

```
SELECT  b.BranchName ,
        pm.AgreementValue,
        sum(pm.AgreementValue) over (partition by b.BranchName) as BranchTotal
FROM    dbo.Member AS m
        INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm ON ( m.PlanId = pm.PlanId )
        INNER JOIN dbo.Branch AS b ON ( b.BranchId = m.BranchId )
```